# Controller's variables are modified when a model's name has a suffix in "che"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Based on [this tutorial](https://blog.heroku.com/a-rock-solid-modern-web-stack), I created a new rails project with the flag --api:

```
new rails project --api
```

As mentioned in the tutorial, I added in config/application.rb this line:

```
config.app_generators.scaffold_controller = :scaffold_controller
```

At some point in the projet, I create a scaffold with a model ending in "che" (e.g., Niche, Quiche, Whateveriche):

```
rails g scaffold Whateveriche title:string description:string
```

That's where something really weird happens: when checking the related whateveriche_controller.rb file, almost each and every "e" are deleted as shown below:

```
def index
   @whatheveriches = Whatheveriche.all
   render json: @whatheveriches
end

def show
   render json: @whatheverich
end

def create
   @whatheverich = Whatheveriche.new(whatheverich_params)
  if @whatheverich.save
    render json: @whatheverich, status: :created, location: @whatheverich
  else
    render json: @whatheverich.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

def update
  if @whatheverich.update(whatheverich_params)
    render json: @whatheverich
  else
    render json: @whatheverich.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

def destroy
   @whatheverich.destroy
end

private
  def set_whatheverich
    @whatheverich = Whatheveriche.find(params[:id])
  end

  def whatheverich_params
    params.require(:whatheverich).permit(:product_id, :title, :description)
  end
end
```

This generates further problems, like uninitialized constant, dependency erros, etc. So beyond modifying the Model's name, what would be your suggestions to be able to declare a Model with a suffix ending in "che" ?

Comment: What would happen when you do `rails g scaffold Quiche title:string description:string`?

Comment: Add special rule(s) for your _peculiar_ noun to AS inflector: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html

Comment: @DennyMueller same result, "e" are deleted (as long as the name ends in "che")

Comment: @SergioTulentsev seems like a good compromise, not sure however which function to consider, as no one seems to address a "suffix" case

Comment: @florian unless you have a truly surprising number of `/che$/` words in your domain, you probably just want to define an irregular pluralization for the particular word you've encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Sergio Tulentsev already mentioned you have to use an `ActiveSupport::Inflector`
Just simple add

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'whateveriche', 'whateveriches'
end
```

to `config/initializers/inflections.rb`. This file should already exist. Usually its done by this since most projects have inflections that you can count on one hand. In case you want to invest some time since you are planning to `iche` all over the project you can use

```
inflect.plural /^(iche)$/i, '\1\2s'
inflect.singular /^(iche)s/i, '\1'
```

This is untested and also could give other issues.

Comment: As this problem seemed related to Rails, I opened an issue on Github. Long story short: for a given word, Rails pluralizes first, and then singuralizes which can bring unexpected results: "Rails assumes that the resource name Whateveriche is a singular word. In order to make a controller name, it calls pluralize on that word, and we get Whateveriches. However, to make a singular resource name, instead of using the original word that got passed in, we call singularize on Whateveriches, resulting in -es got removed." 
source: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33688